# Install ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot with windows on ssd (system is ssd(256gb) and hdd(1tb))

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ssd

The problem I got is that I have installed ubuntu(by help of a guy), but unfortunately it is on separate partition on HDD. And hence its slow. So I want to reinstall Ubuntu on SSD and windows too should be on SSD (as of now).

Comment: So what you need help with exactly? It seems you want a generic tutorial of which there are hundreds online already. You may want to read and understand this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: If the Windows OS has taken all the SSD (meaning you have a single `c:` with 256GB space), then you probably need to re-install both Windows and Ubuntu. If not, just burn Ubuntu as live USB, install it into SSD along with Windows. The wizard should give you an option to select install ubuntu along with windows.

Comment: @MerilynNe there is almost 110 gb free in SSD, and what will happen to the current ubuntu in my system after this installation

Comment: It will do nothing to existing ubuntu system on HDD. You can even copy your important data from Ubuntu on HDD to new Ubuntu on SSD after installation. During the installing process, make sure to select SSD and install alongside with Windows. Also install bootloader in SSD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)